# Actions on Google Android Auto support

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, android-auto

I'm making some tests with "Actions on Google" to add a Google Assistant voice integration of my application.

I tested it on simulator and on my android devices (Phone/Tablet/GoogleHome) that are connected with the same google account and it works well, but on Android Auto running on my phone, Assistant always reply me "MyAppName is not supported on this device" - I can't test it on car with mirrorlink.

Why?

The Action uses just simple audio - it works on a Google Home speaker and does not use the Media response.

Software version info:

- Android Auto 3.7.584044-release
- Google Play Services 14.5.70 (100400-217905028)
- Google app 8.28.7.21.arm64

Comment: I've found there are some versions of Android Auto on some mobile devices that aren't compatible. Can you update your question with the version of the Android Auto app as well as the version of the Google app that you're using to test? Is it possible to test with another phone? Does the Assistant otherwise work on Android Auto (not with your action)? Does your Action require a screen or anything besides simple audio responses?

Comment: @Prisoner Android 9 with last version of Android Auto. No, is it possible to interact only with audio - Google Home device works correctly

Comment: Can you confirm the exact version number of Android Auto, Google Play Services, and the Google app? (And please update your original question - it makes it easier to find.) Good about the audio - just trying to narrow down possibilities. Does it use the Media Response?

Comment: @Prisoner 
Android Auto 3.7.584044-release 
Google Play Services 14.5.70 (100400-217905028)
Google app 8.28.7.21.arm64.
No Media Response

Comment: @Prisoner I forget to say the project still in develop and to publish yet

Answer (score 1):

Google Support team reply me that Android Auto still using Google Now outside USA. Actions on google require Google Assistant, so is not possible to run any custom actions in my country.